# Error in HideShowPanel Method: TypeError: document.all is not a function, c#

Tags: javascript

Error in HideShowPanel Method: TypeError: document.all is not a function

Error in SetExpandedDIVInfo Method: TypeError: document.all is not a function

Comment: You're going to have to give us a bit more context in order to get an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

document.all is not a valid javascript function in non IE browsers. You should use standard compatible document.getElementById